# Any way to disable touchpad gestures in Ubuntu MATE 20.04

Tags: touchpad, mate, gestures

I use Ubuntu MATE 20.04.
I have wide and narrow touchpad and most action activate up-down swipe and cause colapsing active window.
I tryed to find solutions but nothing.
I tryed to read [libinput docs](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/configuration.html)
but it's not complete.

xinput list

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD Mouse            id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ silead_ts                                 id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

xinput list-props 'SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD Mouse'

```
Device 'SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD Mouse':
    Device Enabled (164):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (166): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (302):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (303):   0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (304):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (305):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (306):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (307): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (308): 2
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (309):    1
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (310):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (311): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (312): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (313):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (314):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (315):   1, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (316): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (317): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (287): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (288):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (289):    0, 0
    Device Node (290):  "/dev/input/event5"
    Device Product ID (291):    24704, 32864
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (318):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (319):
```

I can not find property to solve my issues.

I tryed to find it in compizconfig and nothing.

What config file or tool I can use for disabling touchpad swipes?

Comment: In Ubuntu 20.04, there's an option to disable touchpad. Goto Settings->Mouse&Touchpad->Touchpad. You'll find a toggle touchpad option

Comment: As I understand it, the asker does *not* want to disable the trackpad altogether - but rather to use if for cursor movement only, and to disable interpretation of gestures or button presses.

Answer (score 0):

The laptop I'm using has both trackpad and buttons -- Unity, Ubuntu-20.04, Dell Precision 7510.  Certain movements on trackpad were interpreted as button presses, which was happening accidently with moderate frequency.  I want to use trackpad movement for cursor movement only -- and buttons-only for button presses.

My understanding of the question here, is that it requests either the same or very similar.

Went to Settings->Mouse&Touchpad->Touchpad per comment by Akash Karnatak, and under "Touchpad" section found three checkboxes, all enabled by default.
I removed the checkmark to disable "Tap to click", and so far I've been able to move the cursor without accidental button-presses/clicks.

[ ] Tap to click
[x] Two finger scroll
[x] Natural scrolling

See also https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/mouse-touchpad-click.html